# title and labels not showing up in histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am having difficulty with debugging this code here. I cannot seem to figure out why the title and labels do not show. Hopefully, it is not something painfully obvious. But I have gotten this to work just fine with other graphs...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data =[5434, 4948, 4521, 4570, 4990, 5702, 5241, 5112, 5015, 4659, 4806,
   4637, 5670, 4381, 4820, 5043, 4886, 4599, 5288, 5299, 4848, 5378, 
   5260, 5055, 5828, 5218, 4859, 4780, 5027, 5008, 4609, 4772, 5133,
   5095, 4618, 4848, 5089, 5518, 5333, 5164, 5342, 5069, 4755, 4925,
   5001, 4803, 4951, 5679, 5256, 5207, 5621, 4918, 5138, 4786, 4500,
   5461, 5049, 4974, 4592, 4173, 5296, 4965, 5170, 4740, 5173, 4568,
   5653, 5078, 4900, 4968, 5248, 5245, 4723, 5275, 5419, 5205, 4452, 
   5227, 5555, 5388, 5498, 4681, 5076, 4774, 4931, 4493, 5309, 5582, 
   4308, 4823, 4417, 5364, 5640, 5069, 5188, 5764, 5273, 5042, 5189, 4986]

   num_bins = 10
   n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, num_bins, facecolor='blue', 
   weights=np.zeros_like(data) + 1. / 100,alpha=0.5, ec = 'black')
   plt.title = 'Histogram of Shear Strength'
   plt.xlabel = 'Shear Strength of Ultrasonic Spot Welds'
   plt.xticks(np.arange(4000, 6000, step=200))
   plt.ylabel = 'Relative Frequency'
   plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module `plt` provides functions, what you're doing is assigning values to the `plt` module instead of calling the functions.  Except `xticks`, you got that one right.

```
plt.title('Histogram of Shear Strength')
plt.xlabel('Shear Strength of Ultrasonic Spot Welds')
plt.xticks(np.arange(4000, 6000, step=200))
plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: unfortunately, it tells me that the str object is not callable when I write it as you said. That is why I changed it to equals.

Comment: I noticed that plt.bar worked fine with how you said to do it.

Comment: I think the issue is with jupyter. It is now treating the strings as not callable.

Comment: Yup. It works after restarting opening a new notebook.

Comment: That's the nature of python imports.  It imports the module once, and any further imports return the same module.  That's why once you've overwritten the functions they stay overwritten even if you re-import the module.  You have to restart the interpreter as you found out.